# Giving an element with a diagonal edge a border?

Tags: html, css

I want to give this element a border thats wraps fully around with that annoying space at the top right, I can't figure it out. Anyone able to help? I can't find anything that tells me how to this exactly. I'd prefer css only but I'm open to whatever fixes this.

here's what it looks like right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSxGs.png

and here's the code I have:

css:

```
.box {
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    width:340px;
    margin:auto;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding:15px;
    border:10px solid black;
}

.box:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    border-top: 40px solid gray;
    border-left: 40px solid white;
    width: 0;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="zer0">text</div>
```

Comment: Please add your specific html and CSS code. As html and CSS you added doesn't relate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

in .box:before remove this  border-left: 40px solid white;